# Counting Combinations of rows/columns across one table

Tags: sql, select, group-by

I have a query I am having trouble wrapping my head around. What I'm trying to do is come up with a report that will have rows of the major(Accounting, Business, etc) with columns of the type of enrollment(enrolled, withdrawn, etc) with counts for each. Right now, here is my query.

```
SELECT datatel_academicprogramofinterestidname, datatel_prospectstatusname
FROM FilteredContact
GROUP BY datatel_academicprogramofinterestidname, datatel_prospectstatusname
```

Which gives me every combination of these two fields found in my table. I want to get counts for each of the combinations to display. The rows would be the interestidname field, and the columns would be the prospectstatusname field. In every cell there would be a count for how many of that specific combination (Accounting/Enrolled, for example)

I've tried count in multiple ways but can't seem to get it to break the columns out the way I want. Not sure how to use group by, count, and my where clause all in conjunction to have it formatted how I want. The good thing is all my information is in one table, I just can't make it look how I want.

```
|Accounting (BS)                             | Accepted | 25|   
|Acting (BFA)                                | Accepted | 32|    
|Advertising & Marketing Communications (BA) | Accepted | 29|  
|American Studies (BA)                       | Accepted |  2|    
|Accounting (BS)                             | Enrolled |  5|    
|Acting (BFA)                                | Enrolled | 17|    
|Advertising & Marketing Communications (BA) | Enrolled | 40|  
|American Studies (BA)                       | Enrolled | 10|
```

Comment: You don't use `GROUP BY` without an aggregate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be able to use a pivot here.  I created a **[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/38a57/1/0)** to go along with this.  Assuming your primary key field name is p_id

```
SELECT *
FROM FilteredContact 
PIVOT ( count(p_id)
        for datatel_prospectstatusname IN ([Accepted], [Enrolled])
      ) as p
```

Comment: That's really close to what I want. Is there any way to see the prospectstatusname as columns instead of a row?

Comment: I added some data to the question based on the query you wrote for me. Basically I would want the rows to say Accounting, Acting, Advertising, etc. Then the columns would be Accepted/Enrolled, with the counts being the combination of these two fields. It's easier to read as opposed to having them all vertical. I included the counts even though they are not necessary. Those are just the numbers I'm getting right now from my query.

Comment: They represent the amount of times that specific combination of the two fields appears in the table, which is what I'm looking for. I just want the Enrolled/Accepted fields to be columns. I just got this error when trying that SQL: The PIVOT SQL construct or statement is not supported.

Comment: It works flawlessly in SQL Fiddle, but not in my local environment. The Number field is actually only from the query, it's not something in the database itself.

Comment: can you provide the column names in FilteredContact? Are there only the two you provided?

Comment: Those are the only two that matter. There are other columns but none I'm interested in showing.

Comment: updated the query and the fiddle.  assumed your primary key field is named p_id for examples sake

Answer (score 0):

You can easily turn the rows of data into columns using an aggregate function with a `CASE` expression:

```
select interestidname, 
  sum(case when datatel_prospectstatusname = 'Enrolled' then 1 else 0 end) Enrolled,
  sum(case when datatel_prospectstatusname = 'Accepted' then 1 else 0 end) Accepted
from FilteredContact
group by interestidname
```